# Split on column separator in windows

Tags: windows, perl, cmd

```
06/24/2012  09:58 AM                 0 Backup of deleted Report 20120622.xlk
08/20/2012  06:51 PM            28,160 deleted 9 2 Foundation Installs on March 7th.xls
08/20/2012  06:51 PM            31,232 deleted-Installations March 10.xls
08/20/2012  06:51 PM            37,821 deleted Support Process 1.0.pdf
08/20/2012  06:51 PM            57,344 deleted_Support_Process_3_18_2010 V2.vsd
```

Hey guy. I am writing a Perl utility for some file system analysis. I am using DIR in Windows to list out certain files. I want to grab the access date (the first column) and the file name (the last column). Many file names have space so I can't easily split on whitespace. Ideally I should split on the column separator.

- Does anyone know what character I should  spilt on for Windows (XP) output like this to get each separate column?
- Or if there isn't a good character to split on, is there Perl-centric strategy for grabbing the two columns I need?

Comment: Doesn't the Perl `stat` function work on Windows, combined with `opendir`, `readdir`, `closedir`.  Parsing the output of the DIR command is similar to parsing the output of `ls` on Unix — error prone.  If you continue with DIR, split by column numbers (characters): 1-10 is the date and and the name starts at some other position to the end of string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `split` function has an optional third argument to define the max number of strings you split into:

```
my ($date, $time, $ampm, $size, $name) = split /\s+/, $input, 5;
```

Parsing the output of `dir` isn't sensible. You can open a directory in Perl with the `opendir` function and loop over the entries:

```
open my $directory, $dirname or die;
while(defined(my $file = readdir $directory)) {
   next if -d "$dirname/$file"; # skip directories
   my $mtime = (stat "$dirname/$file")[9]; # we use the mtime (last modified)
   printf "%10d %s", $mtime, $string;
}
```

You can consult the documentation for further options of the `stat` function including the array indices for access time or file size. The times are given as Unix time (seconds since 1. Jan 1970 00:00) but can be converted with `localtime` to a more readable format.

Comment: If you do [`use File::stat;`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::stat), you can use `stat("$dirname/$file")->mtime` instead of `(stat("$dirname/$file"))[9]`

Comment: Perl supported functions are much easier, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4):

There exists a pure Perl solution. The [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) function can be used to get the access time.

Otherwise, you could split on whitespace:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ( $date, undef, undef, undef, $name ) = split " ", $_, 5;
    print "$date: $name\n";
}

__DATA__
06/24/2012  09:58 AM                 0 Backup of deleted Report 20120622.xlk
08/20/2012  06:51 PM            28,160 deleted 9 2 Foundation Installs on March 7th.xls
08/20/2012  06:51 PM            31,232 deleted-Installations March 10.xls
08/20/2012  06:51 PM            37,821 deleted Support Process 1.0.pdf
08/20/2012  06:51 PM            57,344 deleted_Support_Process_3_18_2010 V2.vsd
```

You could use `unpack` to consume data *column-wise*.

```
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ( $date, $filename ) = unpack 'A10 x29 A*';
    print "$date: $filename\n";
}
```

Comment: That would split the filenames, which might make things difficult, I really should be able to spilt on column somehow.

Comment: You can avoid the (potentially broken) join, just use `my ($date, $time, $m, $size, $filename) = split " ", $_, 5;`

Comment: Also, you're right that you should just be able to use readdir and stat instead of shelling out to dir. If you don't write it as a full answer, I will :)

Comment: +2 for `stat` suggestion for this problem

Comment: *[hobbs](http://stackoverflow.com/users/152948/hobbs)*: Updated my answer. Thank you. :-)

Comment: `/ /` is not equivalent to `" "`, and you want the latter. No need to rejoin if you impose a limit on the number of fields. You are leaving a trailing newline in `$name`. I fixed those problems and removed unused vars.

Comment: *[ikegami](http://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)*: Thank you for the fixes. :-)